# Modifying devise modules after first generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, devise

I'm in the process of learning rails.  I've found Devise to be great with getting authentication up and running quickly and seamlessly but I do have one question.

How do I change the modules after the first run of the Devise generator (e.g. rails g devise User)?  This defaults with the following migration:

```
def self.up
  create_table(:users) do |t|
    t.database_authenticatable :null => false
    t.recoverable
    t.rememberable
    t.trackable

    # t.confirmable
    # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
    # t.token_authenticatable

    t.timestamps
  end

  add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
  add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
  # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
  # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
end
```

If I've run this migration, how do I add/remove some of those modules at a later stage?  E.g. Maybe I want to add lockable to an existing User model.  I understand how to make the changes in the model and `devise.rb` but I'm not sure what to do with the migrations.

Apologies if the answer is here already, I've trawled for a couple of hours here and in google and couldn't find anything.  Maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing.

Thanks in advance!
Jason
ps. I'm using
rails 3.0.0
devise 1.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the lines you want in the migration file, then redo the migration as per these instructions:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: Hi Chuck. Thanks for the tip.  I'll give it a go.  Is this approach healthy if there are other migrations after the one used for Devise?

Comment: Yes. Rails is smart enough to apply the needed migrations in the order they were added, based on timestamps and internal tracking of which have already run.

Comment: This may work when developping and reapplying all migrations from scratch, but modifying old migration files will NOT work in production, where the system is already at a latter migration state and reapplying migrations will cause data loss. The correct way is to add a new migration file, as per Prakash Murthy's answer.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for answer to the same question, and luckily, happened to be sitting next to someone who knew how to do it.

Here is the example of updating the users model to include confirmable module through a migration script (the skeleton script file generated with **'rails generate migration add_confirmable_to_users'**):

```
class AddConfirmableToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.confirmable
    end
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :confirmable
    remove_index :users, :confirmation_token
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Prakash.  I'll give it a go next time I need to do it :)

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' for #<User:0x000001041531c8> (NameError)
```

To add Confirmable -

Generate the migration:

```
$ rails generate migration add_confirmable_to_users
```

Edit the migration:

```
class AddConfirmableToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :unconfirmed_email, :string
  end
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're just removing options where the appropriate fields were already added to your schema (like confirmable), you can always just edit the Users model directly without a new migration.

Comment: Thanks Joost. I'm also interested in adding items, e.g. t.lockable is not just a field called lockable.

Comment: I think custom types like this you can't do fully from the rails command line, so you'd be able to run 'rails generate migration AddLockableToUsers' and then manually edit the file in the db/migrate folder it generates and add t.confirmable. Then run 'rake db:migrate' and your field is added.